# How to disable angularjs from capturing my form submit for the second submit button

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, angularjs

Thanks for checking.
I am building a web application using angularjs. i have two buttons one will do a Ajax post to server using angularjs and the other will to a normal html post to server. the reason i want the second one to do a direct post to server is that i want to generate an excel document on server and return it tp user to download on response.
please how can i disable angularjs from capturing my form submit for the secont submit button

Comment: can you share your code? html & script

Comment: I think posting my code wont do much. What i am trying to do is similar to this in jquery. e.preventDefault() will prevent html form post but if you omit it the form will be posted as normal. i am looking fir similar feature in angularjs

Comment: angularjs gives the the event object as `$event` in `ng-click` and other methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that the simplest way is to change the button that shouldn't post the form to not be a form button, but another element that doesn't have that default behaviour. That is, change this:

```
<form>
  <input type="text">

  <input type="submit" ng-click="doStuff()" value="Ajaxy things">
  <input type="submit" value="Real post">
</form>
```

to:

```
<form>
  <input type="text">

  <a ng-click="doStuff()">Ajaxy things</a>
  <input type="submit" value="Real post">
</form>
```

And style the `a` to look like a button.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I i am new to angular. i thought i must always include ng-submit to the form.

Comment: You only need ng-submit if you want to hijack the form submission and prevent the browser to post it. In this case, you want the browser to post it, so ng-submit isn't really needed.